# Listview on Windows Phone: Items not listing correctly

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-phone-8.1, viewmodel

My requirement is to implement a list of countries for my user to select and their phone number.
In my desperate attempts, [this](http://mikaelkoskinen.net/winrt-step-by-step-tutorial-mvvm-gridview-semanticzoom/) was the article I followed.
I have a ListView setup this way:

The country names are trial, so it will not make sense.

ViewModel: Where I've hard-coded the list of countries

```
    //Contructor class
    public CountryList_test()
    {
        //Creating static data memberrs (Hardcoded logic)

        var list_countryList = new List
        {
            new CountryList_CountryNames{countryName = "ffsdfndf"},
            new CountryList_CountryNames{countryName = "hfhjf"},
            new CountryList_CountryNames{countryName = "vcxbv"},
                    new CountryList_CountryNames{countryName = "ujhfg"},
                    new CountryList_CountryNames{countryName = "vbcvb"},
                    new CountryList_CountryNames{countryName = "fdfgd"},
                    new CountryList_CountryNames{countryName = "dfdhgfjjyhg"},
                    new CountryList_CountryNames{countryName = "khjkj"},
                    new CountryList_CountryNames{countryName = "fffg"},
        };


        //Grouping the country names    
        var countriesByCategories = list_countryList.GroupBy(x => x.countryName).Select(x => new CountryList_GroupMechanism { countryNameForGroupMechanism = x.Key,countryListForGroupMechanism = x.ToList() });


        countryListForGroupMechanism = countriesByCategories.ToList();
    }


    public class CountryList_CountryNames
    {
        public string countryName { get; set; }
        //public int internationalCode { get; set; }
    }

    public class CountryList_GroupMechanism
    {
        public string countryNameForGroupMechanism { get; set; }
        public List countryListForGroupMechanism { get; set; }
    }


    }
```

```
This looks fine.

This is my Model: It is in the constructor of the class Bpage2

<pre>
public Bpage2()
{

//creating the instance of the View Model and setting it as the data context of the page
    this.InitializeComponent();

    var viewModel = new CountryList_test();
    this.DataContext = viewModel;

}
```

```
This is my View:

        <!--countryListForGroupMechanism comes from the ViewModel-->
        <ListView Name="lstv_countries" 

                  ItemsSource="{Binding countryListForGroupMechanism}" >

        </ListView>
```

And this is my output, and it is driving me nuts. I am sure the issue is in the V-M level, but i don't know where.

[image]

Please help me figure out where the issue is. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: sorry about the formatting. Not sure how that happened.

Comment: Sorry  I missed that: Here it is: public List<CountryList_GroupMechanism> countryListForGroupMechanism { get; set; }. So it is a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expect to see the country names then set the DisplayMemeberPath, so the following should do:

```
<ListView Name="lstv_countries" DisplayMemeberPath="countryNameForGroupMechanism"
          ItemsSource="{Binding countryListForGroupMechanism}" >
</ListView>
```

Or use an `ItemTemplate`

```
<ListView Name="lstv_countries" ItemsSource="{Binding countryListForGroupMechanism}" >
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=countryNameForGroupMechanism}"/>
       </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Neither DisplayMemeberPath nor ItemTemplate worked. It only shows a blank screen. No contents inside. What could be going wrong?

Comment: @AnonymousPerson and now?!  i don't really understand your models